# How to get scipy.stats.spearmanr(A, B) compute correlation only between variables in A and B, and not the whole square matrix?

Tags: python, performance, matrix, scipy, correlation

I have a matrix A of size `10,000 x 50,000` and matrix B of size `8 x 50,000`.
I want to compute Spearman correlation between each row of matrix A and each row of matrix B (80,000 correlations in total). If I do a loop calling `spearmanr` 80,000 times then it takes 2,584 seconds.

If I run `spearmanr(A, B, axis=1)` then the outcome is of size `10,008 x 10,008`, meaning that this method computed 100,160,064 correlations, while I needed only 80,000 of them. However even then it takes less time -- 576 seconds. So obviously this method is much more efficient.

The question is how to use this efficient implementation and do only 80,000 computations I need?

Comment: have you tried with [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) ? something like `np.apply_along_axis(spearmanr(A,B,axis=1))`, it's sort of a guess tell me what it gives ( or show us A & B if possible ). thanks

Comment: I am not sure how do you mean.

`A = np.random.random((5, 10))`
`B = np.random.random((2, 10))`
`spearmanr(A, B, axis=1).correlation.shape`

gives `(7, 7)`, I'd like it to be `(5, 2)`
The code you suggested does not run.

Comment: Looks like `np.apply_along_axis` does a loop behavior: both commands `[spearmanr(A[i,:], B[0, :]) for i in range(10000)]` (just a loop) and `np.apply_along_axis(spearmanr, 1, A, B[0, :])` take same time to compute.

Comment: yeah i noticed that, and it still doesn't suit your needs